# Unable to write on a server using a VM

Tags: powershell

I'm using a PowerShell to open a session in a VM. I can run some code to write in a local folder, but I'm unable to write in a server. Even if I have all rights it gives me "Access Denied".

I'm trying to write on the server first/make folders in the server. I'm using a simple PowerShell that creates a folder.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PassWord' -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("UserName", $secpasswd)
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName NameVM -Credential $mycreds
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    C:\Users\MyName\Documents\CreateFolder.ps1
}
```

```
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\X\X\TestFolderVM:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : VMNAME
```

Comment: Please show the content of the `CreateFolder.ps1` script as well as the complete error message.

Comment: New-Item -ItemType directory -Name "TestFolderVM" -Path X:\

Comment: That code does not match the error shown in your question. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, test-run *that* code, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code as well as the complete error thrown by that code. Do not post code or errors you fabricated or typed from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You got the wrong idea here. PowerShell New-PSSession creates an interactive prompt to the new computer. What you should probably be using instead is something along the lines of:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName HOSTNAME -ScriptBlock CONTENTSOFPS1 -Credentials $creds
```

Comment: still does not allow me to write on the server itself

Comment: Just looking at the error message you posted (\\X\X\TestFolderVM:String), are you trying to edit a file share? If you are, then you need to have NTFS permissions as well as permissions to the actual share.